# Separate page for part title

Tags: parts

I would like to give the title of `\part{title}` a separate page. I would like it to be in the center of the page, both vertically and horizontally. Document class article.

```
                                    PART I
                                  TITLE TEXT
```

Comment: Answering would be much easier if we knew at least which document class you are using... I assume `article` or something based upon it, but that's everything my crystal ball is able to tell me for now...

Comment: In the `memoir` class `\part` is on a page by itself.

Comment: I use the article doc. class and I wouldn't like to change it to memoir.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a mix and revamp of the code for the `article` and `report` classes `\part` macro.

```
% partprob.tex  SE 592540
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\part}{%   % rejig of report/book \part
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%   % mixture of article and report/book code
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \fi
  \markboth{}{}%
  \vfil
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-1\relax
     \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
     \par
     \vskip 20\p@
   \fi
   \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
  \@endpart}

\def\@spart#1{%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
  \@endpart}

\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
    
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{First Part}
\section{A section}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be You will like this one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{1}\begin{center}{\Large\textbf{PART  \Roman{section}} \\ \uppercase{#1}}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\ssection{title}
text
\ssection{title}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use two letter font switches like `\bf` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I should use ```\textbf``` instead, right?

Comment: Yes. And macros like `\Large` are switches, they don't taken an argument.

Comment: Just curious: why do you define the macro to have two arguments, but never use the first argument?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea why my code didn't compile for the first time with one argument (may be I have done something wrong) what is why I made this useless "trick" with two arguments...